# Groovy abstract controller <Domain Class>

Tags: java, grails

Embarrassed, but I can't find the errors in my ways.  No matter what I try `M` is always object (not the actual generic type).  I have a simple setup(`M` is a grails domain):

```
class NewsController extends AbstractController<News> {

}

class AbstractController<M> {

    def show(Long id){
        log.info(M)
        // prints: INFO  common.AbstractController  - class java.lang.Object
        def entity = M.get(id)  //errors
        // .. other code
    }
}
```

Please be gentle, this feels like a brain fart/something stupid.

Comment: What is a propose for this? Have you tried to modify scaffolding template for controller and use dynamic scaffolding(or static)?

Comment: I abstracted all of our code into two very basic controllers, with the hope to be able to use a generic to tie in the underlying domain type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simple as it may be, the alternative I came up with (because of `type erasures`, IMHO a major flaw rendering class generics useless) was:

```
class AbstractController{
    abstract getDomainClass();   
    def show(Long id){
       log.info(getDomainClass())
    }
    def entity = getDomainClass().get(id) 
}

class NewsController extends AbstractController {
    def getDomainClass(){
        return News
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say Type Erasure(or its groovy equivalent).

So the `M` is there just for compile time checking(At least in java). Now how this works in an interpreted language is a little more interesting, but I think your are mostly likely a victim of related circumstances.

It appears that groovy has even stricter requirements throwing away the generic information from source completely. Which probably leads to some interesting behavioral stuff at runtime.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics

Comment: _model = M was just something someone suggested to try, same issue remains.  I think it is type erasure M is always object.

Comment: same thing with log.info(M). The M is meaningless. It doesn't exist after the code is compiled because of Type Erasure.

Comment: So I guess a better question is what are you trying to print out. The generic type of the controller at runtime?

Comment: The print out was just a debugging statement showing that the type was being lost, I gave up with using a generic and create a "template" like pattern instead.